# How to show the default navigation bar in MFMailcomposer view rather than custom nav bar in ios

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, custom-controls, objective-c-blocks

I have a custom navigation bar with image common for all views.Also i have a MFMailComposer view which is presented.But i am not getting the default navigation bar with send and cancel button here.I tried to remove the image from navbar.But not working.This is what i tried:

```
-(void)mailShare:(id)sender{
 [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:nil forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
 Class mailClass = (NSClassFromString(@"MFMailComposeViewController"));

    if (mailClass != nil) {
        //[self displayMailComposerSheet];
        // We must always check whether the current device is configured for sending emails
        if ([mailClass canSendMail])
        {
            [self applyComposerInterfaceApperance];


        }
        else
        {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Device not configured to send mail" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alert show];
            alert = nil;
            return;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Device not configured to send mail" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
        alert = nil;
        return;
    }

    MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;
  // [ picker.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor greenColor]];

    [picker setSubject:@"Try this Pack from FORCE PACKS"];


    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 44, 320, 440);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [self.view.layer renderInContext:context];


    UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();


    // Attach an image to the email
    NSData *myData =  UIImagePNGRepresentation(img);
    [picker addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"image/jpeg" fileName:@"rainy"];

    // Fill out the email body text
    NSString *emailBody = @"I'm on the road to recovery! Check out my latest Exercise Log from FORCE Packs";
    [picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];

    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];

    myData = nil;



}
```

Comment: Could you add the code you're using to customize the navigation bar?

Comment: @Clever Error sure.this is the code: [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navBar.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem in my app. I have removed the code that uses UIAppearance protocol to set Navigation bar image. Instead I set the image for UINavigationBar in every view controller in which I need the customized Navigation bar.

I have created a UIViewController category with a method that I call in `-viewDidLoad` of every UIViewController to customize the navigation bar.

In UIViewController+Appearance.h

```
-(void)changeAppearance;
```

In UIViewController+Appearance.m

```
-(void)changeAppearance{
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"Header"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 6, 0, 6)] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:@{UITextAttributeFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"CooperBlack" size:18], UITextAttributeTextColor: [UIColor colorWithRed:57.0f/255.0f green:132.0f/225.0f blue:168.0f/225.0f alpha:1],UITextAttributeTextShadowColor: [UIColor clearColor]}];

    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setShadowImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"Header-shadow"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 6, 0, 6)]];

    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background"]]];
}
```

First import `UIViewController+Appearance.h` in your view controller's `.m` file and call the `-changeAppearance` method in your view controller's `-viewDidLoad` like:

```
[self changeAppearance];
```

Also remove all the calls that you are currently using to customize Navigation bar like:`[[UINavigationBar appearance] blahBlahBlah]`

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! Here's the code:

```
[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:nil
 forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault]; MFMailComposeViewController
 *emailVC = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init]; //the rest of the implementation goes here... [self presentViewController:emailVC
 animated:YES completion:nil]; Then, I set the nav bar appearance back
 to normal here:

 - (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error
 {
     [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Nav Bar.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
     [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
 }
```